# Why is my output blank?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game that allows me to print an intro which you will see in the code below and then if the user types "menu" a menu will pop up so then it will come up with a list.

This is what my code looks like:

```
def displayIntro():
    print('Hello There What Would You Like Type Menu For The Food Menu')
    print()

    menu = input()
    menu = ['Chips']
    if menu: menu.append('burger')
    else: print("Incorrect Command Try Again")

displayIntro()
```

But when I run it is just blank...

If I do this:

```
def displayIntro():
    print('Hello There What Would You Like Type Menu For The Food Menu')
    print()

    #menu = input()
    #menu = ['Chips']
    #if menu: menu.append('burger')
    #else: print("Incorrect Command Try Again")

displayIntro()
```

It runs the intro perfectly :/

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve from the code.

Comment: First you assign `menu = input()` and then right after you do `menu = ['Chips']`. You are completely overwriting the menu variable and so you're losing the user input. That's definitely not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you using any libraries/modules with this?

Comment: Don't edit the question so substantially once answers are posted, or those answers no longer make sense.

Comment: sorry i just really need help with this it is really annoying me and i have to do it as a task for school...

Answer (score 1):

You set `menu` twice:

```
menu = input()
menu = ['Chips']
```

`menu` used to hold the user's input, but now it refers to `['Chips']`. You have to use a different variable name:

```
user_choice = input()
menu = ['Chips']

if user_choice == 'menu':
    menu.append('burger')
else:
    print("Incorrect Command Try Again")
```

Comment: @ElliottKennethOneill: Can't do anything without seeing how you actually used the code.

Comment: def displayIntro():
    print('Hello There What Would You Like Type Menu For The Food Menu')
    print()
    
user_choice = input()
menu = ['Chips']
if user_choice == 'menu':
else print("Incorrect Command Try Again"):

displayIntro()

Comment: @ElliottKennethOneill: Cramming it into one line isn't very helpful.

Comment: look now i have changed it

Comment: @ElliottKennethOneill: `else` should have a colon after it.